# Optimising Lua code through using local functions

Tags: lua

So, I know that assigning global functions to local variables makes them run significantly faster, like writing code:

```
local _cos = math.cos
for i = 1, 100000 do
    _cos(i)
end
```

Is much faster than code without first localizing the function:

```
for i = 1, 100000 do
    math.cos(i)
end
```

However, based on my tests that doesn't seem to work with things like `tonumber`, `type` or `pairs`.

Could someone clarify why some global functions get significantly faster and others don't seem to be affected at all?

Comment: The only difference that I know of is that getting `tonumber` requires one table access (`_ENV.tonumber`), while getting `cos` takes two (`_ENV.math.cos`). Does localizing `tonumber` really not speed things up at all?

Comment: It's probably about the number of table accesses, as you said. And yes, there's no speed increase when localizing ```tonumber```, which surprised me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localizing global functions doesn't make them *significantly* faster. It makes them *a bit* faster, because you don't have to look them up in `_ENV`; specially if they're in another table like `_ENV.math.cos`. For functions that are directly in `_ENV` this effect is obviously smaller, and if the function itself runs very slow, the tiny difference of localizing it won't be as noticeable.

In fact, you should never localize functions just because. If you have a very small loop body with lots of iterations that calls a very small function, then you should consider localizing it (and you should do that as close to the loop as possible), but only if you're sure this will make a difference (benchmarking is your friend).

There seems to be this persistent myth that just localizing every function you're going to use to the entire library will magically make it faster, which is a total misconception.

LuaJIT even does this itself for most cases; detecting repeated table access within a loop body and localizing it outside the loop.

Also keep in mind that, while `math.cos` shouldn't ever be changed, you might be accessing a function from some other module that actually changes behind the scenes to reflect some state-change in the module. In that case, localizing the function will mean you're working with an outdated function. This isn't very common, but it does happen.

---

Just for fun; try running this in PUC Lua and in LuaJIT:

```lua
local function bench(n, fn, ...)
    local t1 = os.clock()
    for i=1,n do
        fn(...)
    end
    local t2 = os.clock()
    return t2 - t1
end

local n = 1e7

print(bench(n, function() return math.cos(20) end))
print(bench(n, function() return tostring(20) end))
print(bench(n, function() return tonumber("20") end))
print("---------")
print(bench(n, math.cos, 20))
print(bench(n, tostring, 20))
print(bench(n, tonumber, "20"))
```

Comment: I would argue that +30% is a significant performance incrase. My tests, as well as Lua Performance Tips by Roberto Ierusalimschy (see: https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf), show significant performance increases with functions from the math table, for instance. Your explanation as to why this might not be true with entries that are located directly in ```_ENV``` does, however, make sense.

Comment: You won't be getting a +30% increase for everything though; if your function does something like connecting to a database, small details like function localization will get lost completely. As I said, benchmarking really is the best way to decide what to localize, but just doing it for no reason needlessly complicates the code.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - `doing it for no reason needlessly complicates the code` - Can you say the same about `local clock = os.clock` in your code? ;-)

Comment: Arguably, with `n = 1e7`, yes, it's somewhat irrelevant; but to keep that code generic, I tried to avoid the double table lookup right after the end of the loop to make `t2` as close as possible to the actual end of the benchmark.

Comment: Also note that I localize `clock` inside the function, so I'm never keeping the reference for longer than my code is executing; so basically I'm "invalidating my cache" every time I yield control flow back to the calling code just in case `os.clock` changes somewhere else ;D

Comment: After some quick benchmarking there doesn't seem to be a big impact on the measurement even for very small iteration counts, so I'm just removing it anyway. Conclusion: **Always** benchmark. **Never** localize based on intuition alone.